# creating multiple audio streams of an icecast2 server using python-shout

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming, icecast

I am trying to create a web radio server to stream 3 sources at once. I am using python to create a source client for icecast2 using the python-shout library. I am not too familiar with the language (python). however, i got a sample program which does what i need to and more and i have tweaked it for my need. However, I can only create two streams, and after that, i get the error message shown below. I don't know what i'm doing wrong so i hope you guys can help me figure that out.

```
hostname ="localhost"
port= 8000
password = "password"

import shout
import sys
import threading
from glob import glob
from random import shuffle,choice

class RunStream (threading.Thread):
   def __init__ (self, channel_mount, music_directory, station_url, genre,name,         description, bitrate="128", samplerate="44100", channels="5",music_format="mp3", ogv=0):
    #connection to icecast
    global hostname,port,password
    self.song_conter= 0
    self.s = shout.Shout()
    self.s.audio_info = {shout.SHOUT_AI_BITRATE:bitrate,   shout.SHOUT_AI_SAMPLERATE:samplerate, shout.SHOUT_AI_CHANNELS:channels}
    self.s.name = name
    self.s.url = station_url
    self.s.mount = channel_mount
    self.s.port = port
    self.ogv = ogv
    self.s.password = password
    self.s.genre = genre
    self.music_directory = music_directory
    self.s.description = description
    self.s.host = hostname
    self.s.format = music_format #using mp3 but it can also be ogg vorbis
    print self.s.open()
    threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

#checking directories for files to stream
   def scan_directories(self):
      self.files_array = glob(self.music_directory+"/*.[mM][Pp]3")  + glob(self.music_directory+"/*/*.[mM][Pp]3") + glob(self.music_directory+"/*/*/*.[mM][Pp]3")   #checks the specified directory down to the third depth
      print str(len(self.files_array))+" files" #display number of matching files found
      shuffle(self.files_array) # randomize playlist

   def run (self):
      while 1: #infinity
        self.scan_directories() # rescan dir, maybe in time you add some new songs
    self.song_counter = 0   
    for e in self.files_array:
           self.write_future()
           self.sendfile(e)
           self.song_counter = self.song_counter + 1

   def format_songname(self,song): # format song name - on filename (strip "mp3", change _ to " ". Formatting name of song for writing into a text file
      result = song.split("/")[-1].split(".")
      result = ".".join(result[:len(result)-1]).replace("_"," ").replace("-"," - ")
  return result

   def write_future(self): #write playlist
      filename = self.s.mount.replace("/","")+"-current.txt"
      fa = open(filename,"w")
      aid = self.song_counter
      pos = 7 # CHANGE if you want more songs in future playlist
      for s in self.files_array[aid:]:
         fa.write(self.format_songname(s)+"\n")
         pos = pos - 1
         if (pos==0):
            break
      if (pos>0):
         for s in self.files_array[:pos+1]:
            fa.write(self.format_songname(s)+"\n")
      fa.close()   

   def sendfile(self,fa):
      print "opening file %s" % fa
      f = open(fa)
      self.s.set_metadata({'song': self.format_songname(fa)})
      nbuf = f.read(4096)
      while 1:
         buf = nbuf
         nbuf = f.read(4096)
         if len(buf) == 0:
            break
         self.s.send(buf)
         self.s.sync()
      f.close()

#running the first stream
RunStream(channel_mount = "/stream", music_directory = "/home/CUWebRadio1/music_one", station_url = "http://webradio.com", genre = "new",name = "Web Radio Channel2", description = "bla bla bla").start()

#running the second stream
RunStream(channel_mount = "/stream_2", music_directory = "/home/CUWebRadio1/music_twos", station_url = "http://webradio.com", genre = "music",name = "Web Radio Music", description = "bla bla bla").start()

#running the Third Stream
RunStream(channel_mount = "/stream_3", music_directory = "/home/CUWebRadio1/music_three", station_url = "http://webradio.com", genre = "Music",name = "CU Web Radio Music3", description = "bla bla bla").start()
```

**the Error message i get**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_threads.py", line 96, in <module>
    RunStream(channel_mount = "/stream_3", music_directory = "/home/CUWebRadio1/music_three", station_url = "http://webradio.com", genre = Music",name = "CU Web Radio Music3", description = "bla bla bla").start()
  File "new_threads.py", line 37, in __init__
    print self.s.open()
shout.ShoutException: Login failed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turns out that my code is correct. The problem was in the configuration for Icecast. By default, only two streams can be created. after editing that in the icecast config file, It all worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Good job! Is there any difference for shoutcast connection or for icecast(1) connection?
I don't think so, but i don't have any type of those servers to check it.