# IceCast Server Fall back file

Tags: file, fallback, icecast

How do I set up a fall-back file for an IceCast server?

Comment: Are you looking for a fallback when the source stream is disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to be using a very useful toolset named **liquidsoap** with icecast2 then you ought to be thrilled with the follow example, which will **play a directory of sound files, or if there is a live stream broadcast then it will fadeout the playlist, play a "jingle" sound file, then fadeup the live stream**. Aside from the silly urls this was pulled from a working environment.

Installing liquidsoap was as painless as apt-get install. If you want to use mp3 then apt-get install lame and then switch to output.icecast.lame(). Create a file with a .liq extension (example.liq), then chmod +x example.liq and you're off to the ./races

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap 
# use the -d flag for daemon mode

set("log.file",false)
set("log.stdout",true)
set("log.level",3)
set("harbor.icy",true)

default =  single("say:How are you gentlemen!! 
             all your base are belong to us. 
             You are on the way to destruction.                      
             What you say!!                      
             You have no chance to survive make your time! 
             HA! HA! HA! HA! HA!")

jingles = playlist("/home/edward/micronemez-jinglez") 

audio = playlist("/home/edward/micronemez-ogg")

#liveset = mksafe(input.http("http://audio.micronemez.com")) 
liveset = strip_blank(input.http("http://f-dt.com"))
liveset = rewrite_metadata([("artist", "FUTURE__DEATH__TOLL"),("title", "LIVE FROM YELLOW_HOUSE")], liveset) 

radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false,
         [skip_blank(liveset), audio, default])

radio = random(weights=[1,5],[ jingles, radio ]) 

output.icecast.vorbis( 
  host="futuredeathtoll.com",port=8000,password="hackme", 
  genre="Easy Listening",url="http://f-dt.com", 
  description="pirate radio",mount="micronemez-radio.ogg", 
  name="FUTURE__DEATH__TOLL ((YELLOW_HOUSE))",radio)
```

some very useful links:

http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/cookbook.html

http://oshyn.com/_blog/General/post/Audio_and_Video_Streaming_with_Liquidsoap_and_Icecast/

http://wiki.sourcefabric.org/display/LS/WikiStart

Comment: right, so i forgot to mention that you'll need to apt-get install festival (http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) to get the say:  tts parameter to work. Be wary of the multiple streams limit config in icecast2.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303445/creating-multiple-audio-streams-of-an-icecast2-server-using-python-shout) i

Answer (score 2):

From the doc:

```
fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
<fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
<fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>`
```

Please see [icecast2_config_file](http://www.icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.3.1/icecast2_config_file.html) for more explanation scroll to the fallback-mount description.

Comment: The thing is that's just a mount point so you have to make another mount point and feed it too

Comment: From the docs: "A fallback mount can also state a file that is located in webroot. This is useful for playing a pre-recorded file in the case of a stream going down. It will repeat until either the listener disconnects or a stream comes back available and takes the listeners back. As per usual, the file format should match the stream format, failing to do so may cause problems with playback."